# Including value of a variable to an href string javascript

Tags: javascript, php, hyperlink, href

I have this code that works when I want the user to be redirected to another link, with the following:

```
window.location.href="index.php";
```

However, this time I've asked for a user input prior to redirecting. It goes like this:

`var p_value = prompt("Enter value for P");`

I want the link to be constructed in the form:

```
window.location.href="index.php?p=p_value";
```

the page was being redirected but the link was index.php?p=p_value and not what it is supposed to be, Suppose the user entered '10', the link should be index.php?p=10

I've also tried using

```
window.location.href="index.php?p=" + p_value;
```

but still doesnt work, how can I fix this?

Comment: The last attempt using string concatenation should've worked. What actually happened when you tried it? (Is that line in the same function as the prompt()?)

Comment: What's the exact sequence of your code?

Comment: oh oh oh, im sorry for the bother guys, it actually worked.

Comment: @nnnnnn what i post here wasn't exactly what was on my code, and when I read your comment i rechecked and found it differently, then I go try what I post here and yah it worked. so thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in the given sequence:

```
var p_value = prompt("Enter value for P");
var href_construct = "index.php?p=" + p_value;

p_value != null ? (
    console.log("p_value is blank");
) : (
    console.log("Redirecting");
    window.location.href = href_construct;
);
```